# Make my .py file importable from any directory

Tags: python, import

How can I make a `.py` file importable from any directory? If there is a multi-platform solution to this, please do say. Thanks!

Comment: [Create a package](http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html) and then have people install it.

Comment: When you say import, do you mean from another .py you have saved somewhere else? The same way you would import, say, os or time etc?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try modifying the `sys.path` "Array" of directories which python looks in...

```
import sys
sys.path.append(path/of/directory)
import customPyScript
```

That I find is the easiest